# Get Nth element of an array that returns from "string_to_array()" function

Tags: arrays, database, string, postgresql, type-conversion

I am searching for a way to access to the Nth element of an array which is a result of `string_to_array()` function in PostgreSQL. For example,

Assume that a cell contains the string value: "A simple example". If I use `string_to_array()` function, I will have an array of three strings as ('A','simple','example'). Now, without storing (I mean, on the fly) I want to access the 2nd element of this array, which is 'simple'.

During my googling, I saw an example to access the last element of the array but this barely solved my problem.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 196, accepted):

```
select (string_to_array('1,2,3,4',','))[2];
```

Comment: note: this is 1 indexed, ie first element is at position 1.

Comment: Took me reading this to realize I need to put brackets around the function call (other languages are more forgiving in that regard)

Comment: We really need to add this note to the answer, in what world arrays start at 1?

Answer (score 1):

*Memos:

- An array has values from `[1]` but not from `[0]` so `[0]` returns `NULL`.
- Basically, you should use type conversion to create an array except when you declare a non-empty array in a `DECLARE` clause in a function, procedure or `DO` statement because the type may be different from your expectation and there is some case which you cannot create an array without type conversion. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809547/convert-integer-to-string-in-postgresql#77723276) explains type conversion in detail.
- [The doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) explains arrays in detail.
- [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71406989/declare-an-array-in-postgresql#77723752) explains how to create and use the 1D(one-dimensional) array with `VARCHAR[]` in detail.
- [My post][4] explains how to create and use a 2D(two-dimensional) array in detail.
- [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23924815/create-an-empty-array-in-an-sql-query-using-postgresql-instead-of-an-array-with#77932610) explains how to create and use an empty array in detail.

You can get array's elements using [string_to_array()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTION-STRING-TO-ARRAY) with these ways below:

```sql
SELECT string_to_array('1,2,3,4,5', ',')::INT[]; -- {1,2,3,4,5}
SELECT (string_to_array('1,2,3,4,5', ',')::INT[])[0]; -- NULL
SELECT (string_to_array('1,2,3,4,5', ',')::INT[])[2]; -- 2
SELECT (string_to_array('1,2,3,4,5', ',')::INT[])[2:4]; -- {2,3,4}
SELECT (string_to_array('1,2,3,4,5', ',')::INT[])[:4]; -- {1,2,3,4}
SELECT (string_to_array('1,2,3,4,5', ',')::INT[])[2:]; -- {2,3,4,5}
SELECT (string_to_array('1,2,3,4,5', ',')::INT[])[:]; -- {1,2,3,4,5}
```

*Memos:

- The type of the array above is `INT[]`(`INTEGER[]`).
- If you omit `::INT[]`, the array above is `TEXT[]` type which cannot do calculation.
- Don't put any spaces in the 1st argument of `string_to_array()` otherwise the values separated by `,` have spaces.

In addition, you can get array's elements with these ways below:

```sql
SELECT ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5]::INT[]; -- {1,2,3,4,5}
SELECT (ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5]::INT[])[0]; -- NULL
SELECT (ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5]::INT[])[2]; -- 2
SELECT (ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5]::INT[])[2:4]; -- {2,3,4}
SELECT (ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5]::INT[])[:4]; -- {1,2,3,4}
SELECT (ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5]::INT[])[2:]; -- {2,3,4,5}
SELECT (ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5]::INT[])[:]; -- {1,2,3,4,5}
```

*Memos:

- The type of the array above is `INT[]`(`INTEGER[]`).
- Even if you omit `::INT[]`, the type of the array above is still `INT[]`.

Or:

```sql
SELECT '{1,2,3,4,5}'::INT[]; -- {1,2,3,4,5}
SELECT ('{1,2,3,4,5}'::INT[])[0]; -- NULL
SELECT ('{1,2,3,4,5}'::INT[])[2]; -- 2
SELECT ('{1,2,3,4,5}'::INT[])[2:4]; -- {2,3,4}
SELECT ('{1,2,3,4,5}'::INT[])[:4]; -- {1,2,3,4}
SELECT ('{1,2,3,4,5}'::INT[])[2:]; -- {2,3,4,5}
SELECT ('{1,2,3,4,5}'::INT[])[:]; -- {1,2,3,4,5}
```

*Memos:

- The type of the array above is `INT[]`(`INTEGER[]`).
- If you omit `::INT[]`, the value above is not an array and the type of the value above is `unknown`.

And, even if you set `INT[2]` to the array, the result is the same as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5]::INT[2];
    array
-------------
 {1,2,3,4,5}
(1 row)
```

And, the type of the array is `INT[]`(`INTEGER[]`) rather than `INT[2]`(`INTEGER[2]`) as shown below. *You can use [pg_typeof()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html) to check the type of a value:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT pg_typeof(ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5]::INT[2]);
 pg_typeof
-----------
 integer[]
(1 row)
```

And, even if you set `VARCHAR` to `1`, the type of `1` is `INT`(`INTEGER`) rather than `VARCHAR` as shown below because the outer type conversion `INT[]` is prioritized:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT (ARRAY[1::VARCHAR,2,3,4,5]::INT[])[1];
 array
-------
     1
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT pg_typeof((ARRAY[1::VARCHAR,2,3,4,5]::INT[])[1]);
 pg_typeof
-----------
 integer
(1 row)
```

Answer (score -1):

To add the example of what I was looking for:

select product_ids[1] from comments where board_name = '12345678';