# Convert integer to string in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting, type-conversion, postgresql-9.1

How do I convert an integer to string as part of a PostgreSQL query?

So, for example, I need:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE <some integer> = 'string of numbers'
```

where `<some integer>` can be anywhere from `1` to `15` digits long.

Comment: What will you do if your string has leading zeros?

Answer (score 266, accepted):

Because the number can be up to 15 digits, you'll need to cast to an 64 bit (8-byte) integer. Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE myint = mytext::int8
```

The `::` cast operator is historical but convenient. Postgres also conforms to the SQL standard syntax

```
myint = cast ( mytext as int8)
```

---

If you have literal text you want to compare with an `int`, cast the `int` to text:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE myint::varchar(255) = mytext
```

Comment: Ah. I actually needed it the other way around (myint converted to varchar) but your answer was enough to guide me to the right place. I just did `myint::varchar(255) = mytext` and it works. Thanks!

Comment: Strictly, this does not answer the question. The example was not the problem - converting an integer to a char/string was. But thanks, @spyd3rr

Comment: @fred Not so: OP's *actual* problem was unsuccessfully trying to compare numeric and text values. This answer shows how to fix that by casting the text to a number (even though OP tried casting a number to text).

Comment: @Bohemian The question title and text says: "How do I convert an integer to string as part of a PostgreSQL query?". Then an *example* of when this *could* be relevant. In my case, I found this thread because I actually had to convert an integer to a string - not for comparison but for using inside an aggregate function that would fail, if the argument was not a string. In which case, this was not an answer to the question, as it literally reads atm.

Answer (score 201):

You can cast an integer to a string in this way

```
intval::text
```

and so in your case

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE <some integer>::text = 'string of numbers'
```

Comment: This will not work if you're working with SpEL in jpa native queries. You'll have to use cast in that case.

Answer (score 38):

You could do this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE cast(YOUR_INTEGER_VALUE as varchar) = 'string of numbers'
```

Answer (score 10):

And if some integer which could be stored as string contains decimal points and you would want to compare decimal to decimal, below would help

```
select NULLIF('105.0', '')::decimal

SELECT * FROM table WHERE NULLIF('105.0', '')::decimal = 105.0
```

Below won't convert

```
select NULLIF('105.0', '')::int

select NULLIF('105.0', '')::integer
```

For this question you will just go by

```
select 105.3::text
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert `INT` to `VARCHAR` as shown below. *[The doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createcast.html) explains type conversion in detail:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT 123::VARCHAR;
 varchar
---------
 123
(1 row)
```

Or:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT CAST(123 AS VARCHAR);
 varchar
---------
 123
(1 row)
```

In addition, you can use [pg_typeof()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html) to check the type of `123` as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT pg_typeof(123);
 pg_typeof
-----------
 integer
(1 row)
```

And, if you set `VARCHAR(2)` to `123`, the result is `12` as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT 123::VARCHAR(2);
 varchar
---------
 12
(1 row)
```

But, the type of `12` is `VARCHAR`(`CHARACTER VARYING`) rather than  `VARCHAR(2)`(`CHARACTER VARYING(2)`) as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT pg_typeof(123::VARCHAR(2));
     pg_typeof
-------------------
 character varying
(1 row)
```