# Left join of columns with different datatypes in Slick

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

I have an situation where one column is `Bigint` in one table and another one is `varchar`. I am using `Scala` and `Slick` for the application. The problem is I need to do a Left Join on these two columns, but getting compilation errors due to the type mismatch. 
I can change the DB column from BigInt to varchar, but then I will have to make changes in many places. Is there a way in which I can avoid changing the tables and the related entities ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast a value of type `Column` using its method `asColumnOf` with a proper type parameter. This way the generated sql will also contain the cast in the join condition.

Something like:

```
for {
    (a, b) <- aTable.leftJoin(bTable).on(_.someColumn === _.anotherColumn.asColumnOf[Long])
} yield (a, b)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `cast` the integer to string e.g.

```
LEFT JOIN mytable on myint::text = mytext
```

You can also use `CAST(myint as varchar)`

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809547/how-do-i-convert-an-integer-to-string-as-part-of-a-postgresql-query).

Comment: Yes, this is done on the PG Query right? I need to do this in the Slick code.

Comment: What I put is indeed postgresql code. Can't help you with the Slick stuff, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thats fine. Thanks.  I know how to do in SQL, but need to do that in Slick :(