# Create an empty array in an SQL query using PostgreSQL instead of an array with NULL inside

Tags: sql, arrays, database, postgresql, null

I am using the following schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
  person_name VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE pet (
  animal_name VARCHAR,
  person_name VARCHAR REFERENCES person(person_name),
  PRIMARY KEY (animal_name, person_name)
);
```

I wish to create a table where, for each `person_name`, I get an array with the pets of that person. I am using *PostgreSQL 9.3.4*.

I have the following values in each table:

**Person**

```
PERSON_NAME
-----------
Alice
Bob
```

**Pet**

```
ANIMAL_NAME | PERSON_NAME
-------------------------
Woof        | Alice
Meow        | Alice
```

I wish to create the following table:

```
PERSON_NAME | PETS
--------------------------
Alice       | {Woof, Meow}
Bob         | {}
```

I cannot, however, create the empty array. What I get is the following:

```sql
PERSON_NAME | PETS
--------------------------
Alice       | {Woof, Meow}
Bob         | {NULL}
```

This is the query I am using:

```sql
SELECT
  person.person_name,
  array_agg(pet.animal_name) AS pets
FROM
  person LEFT JOIN pet ON person.person_name = pet.person_name
GROUP BY
  person.person_name;
```

I understand why I am getting the array with the `NULL` value inside, I want to know how to get an empty array instead.

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/953b7/3) with the code needed to create the schema, insert the values and with the query I am using. The result shown in the website doesn't show the `NULL` value, although it is there.

**EDIT**

The result will be parsed to JSON, that is why `{NULL}` is not an acceptable result, as it will be parsed to `[null]`, which is different from the `[]` I require. For the same reason, something like `{""}` is not an acceptable result either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simple way of doing this, is to use the [`ARRAY` constructor's sub-query variant](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS):

```
SELECT
  person.person_name,
  ARRAY(SELECT animal_name FROM pet WHERE person.person_name = pet.person_name) AS pets
FROM
  person;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/24ccc/11)

Answer (score 20):

I just wanna add tho this is 6 years old

> array[]::varchar[]

Answer (score 4):

Two possibilities come to mind.

One option is a UNION.

```
select person.person_name, array_agg(pet.animal_name) as pets
from person
join pet on person.person_name = pet.person_name
group by person.person_name

union

select person.person_name, array[]::text[] as pets
from person
left join pet on person.person_name = pet.person_name
where pet.animal_name is null
```

The first part uses a JOIN to get the people with pets, then the second grabs those poor people that don't have any pets at all. Separating them lets you supply a literal empty array for the pet-less people.

Another option would be to do pretty much the same thing using a LEFT JOIN to a derived table:

```
with pet_names as (
  select person.person_name, array_agg(pet.animal_name) as pets
  from person
  join pet on person.person_name = pet.person_name
  group by person.person_name
)
select p.person_name, coalesce(n.pets, array[]::text[])
from person p
left join pet_names n on p.person_name = n.person_name
```

This one is a little more natural to me as it lets you use COALESCE (the first thing you reach for you want to map NULL to something else) to supply the empty array.

Updated demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/24ccc/7

There may be other solutions, these two just seem like natural approaches to me.

Comment: I apologise for changing the accepted answer, but @pozs' answer seems, well, _cleaner_.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `COALESCE` to replace `NULL` values:

```
SELECT
  person.person_name,
  array_agg(coalesce(pet.animal_name,'')) AS pets
FROM
  person LEFT JOIN pet ON person.person_name = pet.person_name
GROUP BY
  person.person_name
;
```

Comment: That gives me `{""}` instead of `{}`. I believe they're not the same.

Comment: @9lo -- I don't know of any other values besides `NULL` and empty strings. Seems you might be talking about presentation logic instead of sql.  This is the result of the above query --  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/59b18/1

Comment: Check the result in psql, via terminal. I did say that the result shown in the fiddle doesn't print the `NULL` value. The result gotten from the query will be parsed to JSON, where `[] != [null]` as well as `[] != [""]`.

Answer (score -1):

You can create and use an empty array with these ways below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71406989/declare-an-array-in-postgresql#77723752) explains how to create and use an array:

```sql
SELECT ARRAY[]::VARCHAR[]; -- {}
SELECT (ARRAY[]::VARCHAR[])[1]; -- NULL
SELECT (ARRAY[]::VARCHAR[])[2]; -- NULL
SELECT (ARRAY[]::VARCHAR[])[3]; -- NULL
```

*Memos:

- If you omit `::VARCHAR[]`, there is [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33716949/how-to-handle-cases-where-array-is-empty-in-postgresql#77932660).

Or:

```sql
SELECT '{}'::VARCHAR[]; -- {}
SELECT ('{}'::VARCHAR[])[1]; -- NULL
SELECT ('{}'::VARCHAR[])[2]; -- NULL
SELECT ('{}'::VARCHAR[])[3]; -- NULL
```

*Memos:

- If you omit `::VARCHAR[]`, the value above is not an array and the type of the value above is `unknown`.

Or:

```sql
SELECT string_to_array('','')::VARCHAR[]; -- {}
SELECT (string_to_array('','')::VARCHAR[])[1]; -- NULL
SELECT (string_to_array('','')::VARCHAR[])[2]; -- NULL
SELECT (string_to_array('','')::VARCHAR[])[3]; -- NULL
```

*Memos:

- If you omit `::VARCHAR[]`, the type of the array above is `TEXT[]`.