# How to handle cases where array is empty in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, arrays, database, postgresql, types

I have a function written in plpythonu.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION temp(t_x integer[])
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
.
.
.
x=plpy.execute("""select array_to_string(select id from A where id=any(array%s) ), ',')"""%t_x)
```

On some cases when t_x is empty I get an error:

> ERROR:  cannot determine type of empty array

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### if-else statement

Pseudocode:

```
if t_x is empty
  x=null
else
  x=plpy.execute....
```

### cast

```
x=plpy.execute("""select array_to_string(select id from A where id=any(array%s::integer[]) ), ',')"""%t_x)
```

**Why cast help?**

```
postgres=# select pg_typeof(array[1,2]);
 pg_typeof 
-----------
 integer[]
```

`array[1,2]` has type `integer[]`

---

```
postgres=# select array[];
ERROR: cannot determine type of empty array
LINE 1: select array[];
```

`array[]` has no type.

---

```
postgres=# select pg_typeof(array[]::integer[]);
 pg_typeof 
-----------
 integer[]
```

`array[]::integer[]` has type `integer[]`

Comment: In any cases You must change this 35 places.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help someone in future.
Table function may receive NULL or Empty Array in that case (equivalent to ALL):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION temp(t_x integer[])
RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
.
.
.
x=plpy.execute("""select array_to_string(select id from A where id=any(array%s) or cardinality(coalesce(array%s,array[]::integer[])) = 0), ',')"""%t_x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create an empty array, then I got the same error as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT ARRAY[];
ERROR:  cannot determine type of empty array
LINE 1: SELECT ARRAY[];
               ^
HINT:  Explicitly cast to the desired type, for example ARRAY[]::integer[].
```

So, I set `::VARCHAR[]` to `ARRAY[]`, then I could create an empty array as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23924815/create-an-empty-array-in-an-sql-query-using-postgresql-instead-of-an-array-with/77932610#77932610) explains how to create an empty array with other ways:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT ARRAY[]::VARCHAR[];
 array
-------
 {}
(1 row)
```