# Partial replace in varchar array postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql

I have two tables in a database. First table is `Book` with columns `Id(varchar(40)), "Name"(varchar(255)), Tags(varchar(40)[])`. Second table `Temp` with columns `"Name"(varchar(255)), Id(varchar(40)), duplicateids (varchar(40)[])`.

I need to write script in postgresql. If any record from the `Book` table in the `Tags` column has an id that matches the element in the `duplicateids` column of the `Temp` table, then replace only this element in the array in the `Tags` column from the `Book` table with the `Id` field from the table `Temp`.

Example
Table "Book"

| Id | Name | Tags |
| --- | --- | --- |
| '1' | 'Book1' | ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3'] |
| 2' | 'Book2' | ['tag4', 'tag5'] |

Table "Temp"

| Name | Id | duplicateids |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 'Temp1' | 'testtag' | ['tag2', 'tag5'] |
| 'Temp2' | 'tag100' | ['tag3'] |

After the script should be:

| id | Name | Tags |
| --- | --- | --- |
| '1' | 'Book1' | ['tag1', 'testtag', 'tag100'] |
| '2' | 'Book2' | ['tag4', 'testtag5'] |

Answer (score 0):

The query below update joins by replacing the first intersection between `Book.Tags` and Temp.duplicateids with `Temp.Id`. This should work if max 1 intersection exists per pairs, because if the intersection is empty set, it will just evaluate to `null` and do not replace anything. However, if there could be multiple integers, then this will replace just the first match. If you want to replace all matches, then I recommend to implement a function that has a while loop, which, while there is at least an intersection does a replacement, until the intersection is empty set. But I refrained from doing that here for the sake of brevity. The query below was untested, let me know if there are any problems with it.

```
update Book
set Book.Tags = ARRAY_REPLACE(Book.Tags, (SELECT UNNEST(Book.Tags) INTERSECT SELECT UNNEST(Temp.duplicateids))[0], Temp.Id)
from Temp;
```

Sources:

- https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-update-join/
- https://www.commandprompt.com/education/array_replace-function-in-postgresql/
- [Postgres - Function to return the intersection of 2 ARRAYs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756871/postgres-function-to-return-the-intersection-of-2-arrays)
- [Get Nth element of an array that returns from "string_to_array()" function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831555/get-nth-element-of-an-array-that-returns-from-string-to-array-function)